# What to use instead of sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.userAgent?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I receive this warning

> [javac] SSLTunnelSocketFactory.java:120: warning:
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection is Sun proprietary API and
>   may be removed in a future release 
>   [javac] + sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.userAgent

for

```
  if(NetworkUtils.isIPV6Compatible()&& NetworkUtils.isValidIPV6Address(host)){
     msg = "CONNECT [" + host + "]:" + port + " HTTP/1.0\n"
       + "User-Agent: "
       + sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.userAgent
       + "\r\n\r\n";
  }
```

Do you have an idea what can I use instead (preferably not a an external jar but from the installed JVM)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default that variable is defined as follows:

```
String javaVersion = "Java/" + System.getProperty("java.version");
String userAgent = System.getProperty("http.agent") == null ? javaVersion : System.getProperty("http.agent") + " " + javaVersion;
```

So you can replace that variable with this one or with the name of your application or with any other string you like (since the resulting string is not the User-Agent of a common browser I assume that no JavaScript or any other code will check for it).